# Quasilinear second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a smooth $u\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$
u^{\prime\prime}+a\left(u^{\prime}\right)^{2}+bu=0\text{ on }\mathbb{R}
$$
with 
$$
u^{\prime}\left(x\right),u^{\prime\prime}\left(x\right)\rightarrow0\text{ as }\left|x\right|\rightarrow\infty.
$$
I assume finding (reasonable) closed form expressions for this is
difficult/impossible. Am I mistaken?

Comment: The best I can get is to reduce the order of the ode and get an expression of the form $u' = f(u)$ with the expression refusing to be solved analytically. So are you looking for a solution or qualitative behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The study below shows that the analytical solving leads to the function $x(u)$ on the form of an integral which cannot be expressed on a closed form with the available standard functions. A-fortiori the inverse function $u(x)$ cannot be expressed on a closed form.

So, the inverse function $x(u)$ on the integral form seems the most elaborate result that can be achieved.

Also, it is shown that the conditions specified at infinity are satisfied if $b<0$ . The asymptotic behavior is :

$$u(x)\sim e^{-\sqrt{-b}|x|}$$

Another important point is the non-uniqueness of the solution (a constant in the final result cannot be determined from the specified boundary conditions). This means that the given boundary conditions at infinity are not sufficient. A boundary condition at finite value of $x$ should be necessary to fully determine the solution of the problem.

[image]